# Masonry imagesLoaded javascript error

Tags: masonry

After enqueing scripts as per WP codex and WP Beginner tutorial the site has a Javascript error:  Uncaught ReferenceError: imagesLoaded is not defined

Many others also have this problem.

Link: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-use-masonry-to-add-pinterest-style-post-grid-in-wordpress/

Comment: It is not nice to just point to a problem/link. Please paste your code if possible and explain the problem clearly.

Comment: check the order of js files loaded on site source code.

Answer (score 2):

Followed the same article and ran into the same issue; the author (Josh Pollock) posted a [followup](http://joshpress.net/blog/using-masonry-2-3-wordpress-3-9/) on his blog.

Essentially from WP 3.9, Masonry is there for you to use so all you need in functions.php is:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'slug_masonry' );
function slug_masonry( ) {

    wp_enqueue_script('masonry'); // note this is not jQuery

}
```

and then initialize:

```
//set the container that Masonry will be inside of in a var
var container = document.querySelector('#masonry-loop');
//create empty var msnry
var msnry;
// initialize Masonry after all images have loaded
imagesLoaded( container, function() {
    msnry = new Masonry( container, {
        itemSelector: '.post'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used code from above link then replace `wp_enqueue_script('masonry')` with `wp_enqueue_script('jquery-masonry')`. Try it and let me know.